# SQL CTE - Recursion Slow due to children of children of children....:

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have a table with parent and child relationships. There's around 10,000 records (other tables like this may be above or below this number). 
[table preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzEhB.png)

I've set the pk_primarykey column as a clustered index, and the parent and child column as non clustered indexes.

So, end goal is to loop through each child, and recursively identify all children for each value. Since I want to traverse through the entire list of children, restricting this with a recursion level isn't an option.

For instance, I use the below query for child 568866, and it takes around 10 seconds to return 18039 rows (children of children of children... the entire list). For one value, it's not too bad, but when I loop through each of the 10K child records, the time really adds up.

If someone could suggest a way of speeding the record retrieval, it would be very helpful.

```html
with trace_tree (pk_primarykey, childid) as 
(select pk_primarykey, childid from #parent_child_relationships where childid = 571951 
union all 
select c.pk_primarykey, c.childid from #parent_child_relationships c join trace_tree p 
on p.childid = c.parentid) 
select pk_primarykey from trace_tree where childid <> 571951
```

Comment: So you want all tree descendants of a node?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using labeling schemes? There is a number of them out there. One of the most common ones is a containment labeling scheme. You simply assign a node label to each node in the tree like this

[image]

These labels can be assigned to each node using one preorder traversal of the tree (if the stack is used). These labels can be added to your table as a new attributes `start`, `end`. Once the labels are calculated you need to create indexes like this `table(start, end, pk_primarykey)` and `table(childid, start, end)`. If you want to find descendants of a certain node then you process:

```
select t2.pk_primarykey
from #parent_child_relationships t1
join #parent_child_relationships t2 on t2.start > t1.start and t2.end < t1.end
where t1.childid = 571951
```

or maybe more easily, if you have a `start` and `end` value of a node for which you need the descendants (for example (100, 200)) then the query can be

```
select pk_primarykey
from #parent_child_relationships on start > 100 and t2.end < 200
```

in such case, the second index is not needed.

Comment: I tested it, and unfortunately this gives me only the immediate children of the parent. I'd want to go through the list, and recursively get the children of children... Ultimately until there are no children left.

The recursive query I used (noted in my original question) gives me the correct results, but problem is, it's just too slow.

Comment: @Logically_Sound then your numbering is probably wrong. It is difficult to debug if there are no sample data prepared.

Comment: Radim Bača: I've uploaded the table, including the numbering system I used, as a spreadsheet here. https://ufile.io/sc30n

Comment: As an update: I ran a query to get the recursion levels, and it went all the way to level 54. Here's an updated spreadsheet with those results (Sheet 2). https://ufile.io/n3fx1 

with trace_tree (pk_primarykey, childid, recursion_level) as 
(select pk_primarykey, childid, 1 as recursion_level from #parent_child_relationships where childid = 47088 
union all 
select c.pk_primarykey, c.childid, recursion_level+1 from #parent_child_relationships c join trace_tree p 
on p.childid = c.parentid) 
select pk_primarykey from trace_tree where childid <> 47088

Comment: You clearly did not get the idea of the labeling scheme. I have come across a different term used for the containment labeling scheme: nested set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model Check this wikipedia article, maybe it will make the idea more clear.

Comment: Baca: Thanks, I checked it out. However, wouldn't that be applicable for a strictly heirarchical data structure? Something like a top level parent encompassing several children who each then have their own children within them? Something like this (http://mikehillyer.com/media//numbered_tree.png, http://mikehillyer.com/media//nested_numbered.png).... In my data, there's no heirarchy or a tree structure..

Comment: I was asking you at the beginnig whether you are interested about descendants in a tree ...